# Schedule a cronjob via Python3 script

Tags: python, cron

I need a python script to run every 2 minutes. Is there a possible way to run `script.py` FROM a python script?

I would want this added to the crontab:

```
*/2 * * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script.py
```

Reminder: I do NOT want to use crontab -e. I specifically want to create a cronjob from a python script.

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem or what is it missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read about you dont want to use crontab but i would like to know why and I would give my solution with crontab. The solution that @Kushim propposed is indeed a bad approach since you are not only creating the execution of 2 minutes "by hand" but also you do not get any information or output of your script unless it raises an Exception.
To define a job each 2 minutes you should first execute in your terminal:

```
crontab -e
```

and add this at the end:

```
*/2 * * * * ./run_script.py >> crontab.log 2>&1 #2>&1 redirects errors to stdout
```

So run_script.py will run each 2 minutes. Now, to call the other script from run_script.py you can write this in run_script.py

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['python3', 'other_script.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(result.stdout)
```

Whether your other_script.py raises and exception or not it will be managed by subprocess and it will be written in a log file to check the output.

Comment: This is not following what I requested. I do NOT want to use crontab -e in a terminal. I am trying to do this 100% in a python script. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install runpy library:

```
# scheduler.py
import traceback
import time
import runpy #https://www.tutorialspoint.com/locating-and-executing-python-modules-runpy
from datetime import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            runpy.run_path("./your_script_to_run.py")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error occurred during execution at " + str(datetime.now().date()) + " {}".format(datetime.now().time()))
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            print(e)
        finally:
            # Sleep for 2 mins
            time.sleep(120)
```

Now just run your script from the terminal like so:

```
python scheduler.py
```